# JQUERY DateTimePicker no Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I just wanna ask why my JQUERY DateTimePicker looks like below image

[image: JQUERY DateTimePicker]

I don't know why it doesn't have any design

Site.Master

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-GB.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(function () {
        $(".frmdate").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["en-GB"]);
    });
```

Let me know what causes the datetimepicker to look like that...

Comment: have you included css file of jquery datetimepicker ?

Comment: you need to include <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> as well refer https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Take a look on this example : https://jsfiddle.net/kmu4rru4/

Comment: @Ripun Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to insert this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```